# How to implement a exponential type constraints in CVXPY

Tags: constraints, exponential, cvxpy

This is in reference to my current direction of work in the field of Markov decision process. I am trying to implement certain constraint that requires me to take power of a matrix **"lets say A"**. Now the constraint looks like **cp.power(A,N) == C**; where A is a convex variable of size {N \times N}, N \in \mathbb{Z}, C \in \mathbb{Z}^{N \times N}. I am unable to implement this form of constraint as **cp.power(A,N)** only takes convex curvatures and hence equality constraints are not disciplined convex or DCP.

Could you please help me in implementing these form of constraints or if you could direct me to some workaround would be great.

Regards,
Dr. Pratik Bajaria

Comment: What is a "convex variable"? Anyway, any nonlinear equality constraint is nonconvex, so not allowed.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen, Thanks for your response. Although, as you have rightly pointed out "any nonlinear equality constraint is nonconvex and not allowed", I am using a standard "<=;>=" to emulate equality constraint. But, I am still unable to implement this inequality in CVXPY. Do you mean to say that, irrespective of any formulations I do an equality constraint of nonlinear form would render the solution infeasible?

Comment: @PratikBajaria It is impossible to model the ordinary power of a matrix (of dimension bigger than 1) in a DCP-compliant way, whether you would would use it in an equality, inequality, or elsewhere. It is not even convex nor concave as a function of the matrix elements. I am guessing you are asking about the ordinary linear-algebraic power under matrix multiplication, right?

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek Yes, thats true. I am looking for a simple matrix multiplication constraint of certain power equals a known numerical matrix.

Comment: @PratikBajaria Well that is a horribly non-convex multivariate polynomial constraint of degree N. Not for cvxpy for sure.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek In which case, is there a possibility to implement Maximize(cp.power(A,N)[0,:]) subject to "some constraints"? I understand that maximization can only happen on a scalar but is there a possibility to implement a constraint which says that either maximize **some row** or make sure that **some row** is maximum amongst all the other row vectors of a matrix. Kindly suggest.